# How to copy data from shared memory to a text file?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, shared-memory

Overview:

The child process takes a number n from on command line where n is the number of students. The data of students (name and marks) is entered on command window.

Now this data is to be copied in shared memory. The parent process is to then take this data from shared memory and copy in a file. This is what I'm having trouble with. How do I copye this data from shared memory onto a file?

```
struct student {
                char name[20];
                float marks;
               };
               
               
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   key_t key = 10;
   int shmID = shmget(key, 100, 0666 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL);
   pid_t pid;
   pid=fork();

   if(pid==0) 
    {
     //Child writes data of n number of students
     char* child_at = (char*) shmat (shmID,NULL,0);

     int i,n;
     int a = 0;
     n = atoi(argv[1]);
     struct student stuarr[n];
     printf("Number of students: %d\n",n);


     for (i=0;i<n;++i)
     {
       printf("For student %d\nEnter name: ",i+1);
       scanf("%s",stuarr[i].name);

       printf("Enter marks: ");
       scanf("%f",&stuarr[i].marks);

     }
     printf("\n\tName\tMarks\t\n");

        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
                printf("\t%s\t%.2f\t\n", stuarr[i].name, 
                stuarr[i].marks);



        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
         {
           memcpy(child_at + (a * sizeof(struct student)), &stuarr[i], 
           sizeof(struct student));
           a++;
         }
         int d1 = shmdt(child_at);

}

else if (pid>0)
{
   //Parent creates shared memory, waits. Then writes data of students 
   to file
   char* parent_at = shmat(shmID, NULL, 0);
   wait(NULL);
   int i, n = atoi(argv[1]);
   struct student stuarr[n];
   FILE *fptr;
   fptr=(fopen("student.txt","w"));

   if(fptr==NULL)
   {
     printf("Error!");
     exit(1);
   }

   for (i=0;i<n;i++) 
   {

      //HOW TO COPY DATA FROM SHARED MEMORY TO FILE? 

      //memcpy(&stuarr[i].name, &parent_at[i], n);
      //memcpy(&stuarr[i].marks, &parent_at[i], n);

      fprintf(fptr,"\nName: %s", stuarr[i].name, stuarr[i].marks);
   }

   fclose(fptr); 
   int d2 =shmdt(parent_at);
   shmctl(shmID, IPC_RMID, NULL);

}
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and indent your code.

Comment: `fprintf` works just fine for putting data into a text file.  The problem is that you're trying to get the data from `stuarr`, which is a local array that is not shared in any way, so you're just printing garbage.  You need to be reading out of the block of memory which `parent_at` points to, just the reverse of what you did in the child.

Comment: How do you write *anything* to a file?  The data to write being resident in shared memory does not change that.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Done

Comment: @NateEldredge Alright. Got it. Thank you :)

Comment: Please add your  preprocessing directives too!